# Proper database structure for a "Guild" system?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

My current structure has a table for accounts, and characters which are relative the the account's "ID" field. These characters also have their own unique ID, which I was going to use in the guilds table; However I then realized I couldn't figure out the best way to handle it.

Should I just create a TEXT field and store the character ID's there using a seperator? That seems strange to do, because each character would have it's own rank in the guild, etc, etc. However, it seems that using the logic that you want to be able to store when a player joined a guild, what his rank is in the guild, or any other information, each guild would need it's own table.

What's the proper structure for this? Should I have a "Guilds" table, or a "Guilds" database which has a table for each guild.

What would you guys recommend, I'm not that good with databases, but I wanted to add a guild type system to my hobbyist project.

Comment: Try not to break the [Zero, One or Infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) rule, and always pay attention to proper [database normalization practices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) when designing data structures. Your idea of a field using a separator should be a **red flag**, those are really difficult to query and cannot be indexed. Instead create a structure with one-to-many (character can belong to one guild only) or many-to-many relationships (character can belong to many guilds).

Comment: Cold anyone explain why this question was downvoted?

Comment: It's because you haven't demonstrated any effort in trying to find a solution. Showing a rough schema, even one that may be totally wrong, is a lot better than nothing.

Comment: @tadman - Thanks, I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should have these tables:

```
ranks(id, name, lower_rank_id, higher_rank_id, description)

guilds(id, name, gold_amount)

characters(id, name)

memberships(id, character_id, guild_id, rank_id, description)
```

You have all ranks in the `ranks` table, all the guilds in the `guilds` table, some characters in the `characters` table and `memberships` table links them all through the foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but seems rather messy.

Comment: @Christian.tucker There's nothing messy about that. This is perfectly by the book.

Comment: Like I said it all makes sense, it just seems messy(all over the place) to me. I understand it perfectly and it's exactly how I've done everything else to this date(So I don't know why it's bothering me), I was just over-thinking it, or rather trying to over-simplify it, and that was causing a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is pretty trivial - at least if the hierarchy only involves:

one or more characters ARE MEMBERS OF zero or more guilds.

Things get slightly more complex if a guild is somehow part of larger guild (i.e. members of the  Woodworker Guild are de-facto members of the Artisans Guild).

Here is a pointer to a [simple hierarchy structure in mySQL](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html) (just replace Employee with Character and Department with Guild and you should be ok) - note that this has also interesting extra features like Guildmasters, the possibility to belong to more than one guild, and to change guild or title/rank over time - you can safely drop some of the extra tables if you don't care for that...